# Jquery: get canvas image to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, canvas

I am trying to send one image from canvas and save it at server using ajax. My Jquery code is like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#UpLoad").click(function () { // trick by a button
            var canVas = $('#Canvas')[0];
            var dataURL = canVas.toDataURL();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'savePicture.php',
                data: { imgBase64: dataURL },
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But when I checked with  the console, i sent a blank data file (since I console log the data I was sending.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: I thought you need form data for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata

Comment: There were any error.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to convert the ImageURL to blob
2. Append the blob into formdata
3. Ajax upload into server

Please give credit to the below post!
[Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {
      type: mimeString
    });
  }
  $("#UpLoad").click(function() { // trick by a button
    var canVas = $('#Canvas')[0];
    var dataURL = canVas.toDataURL();
    var blob = dataURItoBlob('dataURL');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imgBase64', blob);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'savePicture.php',
      data: formData,
      contentType: false, //need this
      processData: false, //need this
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```