# ajax POST is driving me nuts. Code seems right but fails on send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending a canvas image using ajax to a php page that will catch it. Console tells me it is failing every time and not even sending. I have double checked everything and still am not seeing the issue. I finally walked away from it for a week and came back to it and for the past few hours I am still not seeing the issue. What am I over looking? The jQuery version on the server is 2.2.4

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
var pngImage = new FormData();
pngImage.append('Image', dataURL);

$.ajax({
  url: 'upload.php',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType : 'text',
  data: pngImage,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("sucessful send:");
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('failed');
  }
});
```

UPDATE: When using

```
    var Grabcanvas = document.getElementById("signature");
    var ImgData = document.getElementById("Image").value = Grabcanvas.toDataURL();

    var pngImage = new FormData();

    pngImage.append('Image', $('#signature')[0].toDataURL());

    console.log(ImgData); 
    console.log(pngImage);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType : 'text',
      data: pngImage,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(data) {
      console.log("sucessful send:");
      console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(d) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(d);
      console.log(d.responseText);
      }
```

`var ImgData` returns the proper canvas data however `var pngImage` is empty and returns as `FormData { }` in the console.

Comment: What happens when you get rid of these options `cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false`

Comment: Still fails except i get the error `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the console/network attempt?

Comment: I just looked up an instance where I am sending Canvas data and I have these parameters: `contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'html',`

Comment: What triggers the ajax call? What is the failure in the console?

Comment: Try converting your ImageUrl to Blob first. See this for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488200/jquery-get-canvas-image-to-server)

Comment: Check your URL. Generally, 404 occur while url is not accessible or reachable and 500 occur if the server is not responding.

Comment: the only other thing the console shows me is referencing where in jQuery it is failing. `jquery.min.js:2882:39` As far as the network it only shows me that the page loaded and gave the OK 200 response. Nothing else is there meaning it isnt even submitting

Comment: Do you want to send image or whole form data ?

Comment: The signature for the `error` callback is `function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. Why don't you try logging some of that important data rather than just _"failed"_? Is the console telling you anything else other than _"failed"_?

Comment: you need to select your canvas element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think because you are not get correct element for pngImage.

dataToURL() i used for native javascript dom, not jquery dom.

this means if id of canvas is `#canvas`, you should doing this:

```
var pngImage = new FormData();
        pngImage.append('Image', document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL());
```

or in jquery

```
    pngImage.append('Image', $('canvas')[0].toDataURL());
```

so our code will be like below:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="5" height="5"></canvas>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var pngImage = new FormData();
        pngImage.append('Image', $('#canvas')[0].toDataURL());
        
        $.ajax({
          url: 'upload.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType : 'text',
          data: pngImage,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log("sucessful send:");
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(d) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(d); //show error
            console.log(d.responseText); //show error reponse text
          }
        });
    })
    </script>
```

php

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

you will see

```
sucessful send:
Array
(
    [Image] => data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAADElEQVQImWNgoBMAAABpAAFEI8ARAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
)
```

UPDATE:

sry i need to lunch first ^_^

1. why you cant catch POST using $_POST? because you miss write the syntax, and i copy paste your code without read carefully. (so, this is lucky for me to use $_REQUEST XD)

`method: 'POST'` => no method named as `method` in jquery ajax. the right method is `type: 'POST'` , then you can catch it using $_POST. (try to change to $_GET too for learning)

#### huft... how can i miss that

2. you want upload image using binary/blob style but your data is actually just string/text. in this case, i really prefer doing this way

.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="5" height="5"></canvas>
<script>
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {Image: $('#canvas')[0].toDataURL()},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(d) {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
})
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

Comment: Say something about your answer how and why this address op's question?

Comment: Its definitely sending now. Errors are gone and its transmitting data. I just have to rewrite the php to catch the data. I am guessing due to it sending an array I can just catch it with a `$_REQUEST`? I very much thank you. You solved the issue I have had in seconds. Much appreciated

Comment: @Micha `$_REQUEST` is catch POST and GET. `$_GET` only for GET, `$_POST` only for POST. why i using $_REQUEST instead $_POST? because i want to use it for no reason. really for no reason. the right way is using $_POST, because we using `method: 'POST'` in our ajax

Comment: I was asking as `$img = $_POST['Image'];` wasn't returning results to me. I have never has to retrieve an array so I was a bit unclear. Unless as it is an array I need to grab it by key and id such as `$img = $_POST['Image'][0];`

Comment: @plonknimbuzz I am seeing there is many differences between jQuery and javascript. Good to know. I really appreciate the time you took to help and educate me on this. Thank you

Comment: I do notice everything sends fine however the array in the `console.log` is empty. no data is being sent. The canvas is being called by id and when i set an alert to show the canvas it shows fine as well. I dont get it. How could the value be empty?

Comment: you can open new thread. because thats will be different according to your main question. and the main things is, you need to post your code and the explaination

Answer (score 0):

For an example think this is your element,

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="5" height="5"></canvas>
```

Now you need to select this element,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

And

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Then you can send via Ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'a.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: dataURL,
   success: function(data) {
      console.log("sucessful send:");
      console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(d) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(d); //show error
      console.log(d.responseText); //show error reponse text
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So for those of you that are having trouble with sending an image from a canvas through AJAX here is an answer. Nobody would give me correct information on here or just wanted to be jerks and keep down voting. I found someone nice enough somewhere else to explain my issue. When the canvas is converted to a dataURL using `toDataURL()` you have to remove `data:image/png;base64,` from the dataURL string or it will not send. This was acheived by a simple line which is `var png = ImgData.split(',')[1];` The data now sends no problem and can be picked up in PHP and converted no problem. I sincerely hope this helps someone in the future as it caused me a lot of issues getting a CORRECT answer.

```
var Grabcanvas = document.getElementById("signature");

var ImgData = Grabcanvas.toDataURL();

var png = ImgData.split(',')[1]; //THIS IS WHAT DID IT

$.ajax({
  url: 'upload.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'text',
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  data: {"Image" : png},

  success: function(data) {
  console.log("sucessful send:");
  console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(d) {
  console.log('error');
  console.log(d);
  console.log(d.responseText);
  }
```